# Como funciona o processo de exclusão de tags (burnination)?

Tags: suporte, tags

Existe um processo definido sobre como deve funcionar o pedido de remoção de tags no SOpt? 
Procuro algo que responda, em português, perguntas como:

- [O que é?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640/155051)
- [Como funciona?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination)
- [Quando usar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239190/155051)
- [Quando não usar?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273088/460775)

Esse processo existe e possui tag própria nos sites da SE, como por exemplo no [MetaSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/burninate-request/info) e no [SOen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info)

Comment: Acho que não funciona/não existe... :P

Comment: Esse é meu medo,  @GuilhermeNascimento... :P

Comment: Seu medo e uma realidade, creio que só o SOen tenha tal ferramenta e é uma coisa totalmente manual, que só sob solicitação possa se executada, a partir do momento que ela se tornar uma ferramenta melhor, menos manual provavelmente será implementada nos demais sites, claro isso é o que presumo com as infos que tenho, mas só o Gabe pode afirmar... No momento que isto passar a existir todas perguntas sobre tags serão resolvidas :D